# Programa se corta en el primer case de un switch dentro de un do while

Tags: java, bucles, switch

Tengo un problema con un switch donde meto métodos en cada `case`.

El problema es que al terminar el `case` 1 el programa se corta y no entiendo el porqué.

Quiero que me siga repitiendo el menú para poder volver a elegir una opción (sería la opción segunda después de hacer la primera).

```java
do {
        
     
        ***System.out.println("maquina expendedora de agua y tigreton");
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------");
        System.out.println(" 1.recargar y poner precios");
        System.out.println(" 2.comprar producto");
        System.out.println(" 3.salir");
        System.out.println("elige la opcion (1-3)");***
        
        
        
        opcionoperacion=leerporteclado.nextInt();
          
           
        switch(opcionoperacion)
           {
            case 1: 
                
                objetomaquina.metodo_meteclave_y_recarga_monedas();
               break;
                
               
            case 2:
                objetomaquina.comprarproducto();
                break;
               
                
            case 3: 
                objetomaquina.metodo_salir_y_actualizar_productos();
                break;
    
           }  
       
        }  while(opcionoperacion!=3 && claveintroducida.equals(clavecorrecta));
```

El método al que llama en el `case` 1 y que tengo en otra clase es el siguiente:

```java
public void metodo_meteclave_y_recarga_monedas()
    {
        do
        {                    
            System.out.println("ingrese la clave de acceso para recargar la maquina");
            claveintroducida=leerporteclado.next();
            if(claveintroducida.equals(clavecorrecta)){
                System.out.println("clave correcta, puede recargar la maquina");
                contador=3;
                System.out.println("----------------------------------------------");
                System.out.print("recargo agua con.....");
                agua=leerporteclado.nextInt();
                System.out.print("recargo tigretones con.....");
                tigreton=leerporteclado.nextInt();
               
                System.out.println("----------------------------------------------");
                System.out.print("precio agua....." +precio_agua+" euro");
                
                System.out.println("precio tigreton....." +precio_tigreton+" euros");
                System.out.println("----------------------------------------------");
                
                System.out.print(" recargo monedas de 50.....");
                moneda50cts=leerporteclado.nextInt();
                System.out.print(" recargo monedas de 1 euro.....");
                moneda1€=leerporteclado.nextInt();
                System.out.print(" recargo monedas de 2 euros.....");
                moneda2€=leerporteclado.nextInt();

            }else
            {System.out.println("clave incorrecta");
            contador++;
                    if(contador==3)
                    {
                        System.out.println("maquina bloqueada por fallo de acceso");                            
                    }
            } 
        } while (contador<3);
    }
```

¿Alguna idea de por qué el programa no me sigue mostrando el menú de opciones después del `case` 1?

Comment: La sentencia de 'break' es de tipo de control de bucles. Dentro de la iteracion en un bucle, de cualquiera de los tipos (while, do-while, for), el uso de esta sentencia ROMPE la iteracion de dicho bucle.

Comment: Has probado cambiando el comportamiento del bucle, ya sea quitando o cambiando el break; ?

Comment: Quizá sea porque el while no te vea la variable "claveintroducida", no se a que nivel la has declarado y si el método desde donde llamas al método metodo_meteclave_y_recarga_monedas() tiene acceso a la variable. Como en éste método ya evalúas si la claveintroducida es o no es correcta, puedes hacer que el méodo retorne un valor booleano true/false y usarlo en el while en lugar de volver a evaluar la claveintroducida.